# Test existence of subarray in ndarrray

Tags: python, numpy

For a `numpy` array of shape `(n, 2)`, n points with 2 coordinates, what is the best way (fastest for large n) to test if a particular point is already in the array. E.g.

```
test_point = np.array([1, 2])
array_A = array([[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 1]]) # test on this should return False
array_B = array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]]) # test on this should return True
```

Comment: Do you actually have to use ``numpy`` for this? For direct or random access (which do not really benefit from vectorisation and locality), Python's builtin types are very powerful – a ``set`` of ``tuple``s should do this efficiently.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not necessarily, however, I want the output to be of this form and the points are given as numpy arrays.

Comment: @Ali_Sh Thank you, this pretty much what I have been looking for!

Comment: @fales your welcome. Besides using just python and numpy, there are other libraries such as [numba](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ieMvWKKY3-NkTovu9iVab7h5XnAVnCiU?usp=sharing), which could result in more faster runs.

Answer (score 1):

```py
(array_A == test_point).all(axis=1).any()
```

Explanation:

`array_A == test_point` applies broadcasting rules and returns array of booleans with shape equal to array_A.
`.all(axis=1)` returns True for rows if all values are True
`.any()` returns True if any value in column is True

Answer (score -1):

Kindly verify if this is what you were anticipating:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([1,2])
sample = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2]])
result = any([all(sample[i,:] == test) for i in range(sample.shape[0])])
```